# How can I display algebraic expressions as a String?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I display some calculus with variables and indices as a String in android? Or even just a simple radical sign over some numbers?

Comment: Do you mean display the formula? If so, MathView could help you: https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` in Android supports UTF-8, so you can use non-typical characters like: ≠, ÷, =, ∑, ∈, etc.

Full list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: But you can't put anything on or under the Sigma for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use **unicodes**

You can get list of unicodes from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode)

for example 
If you want to use **∑** use

`android:text="/u2211"`

attribute in xml

**OR**

`textView.setText("/u2211")`

You can also use in HTML like

`.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));` for X^2